# how to write a exponent value in php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, exponential

How to write `9.2903e-6` in php?

I have to convert sq-feet to hectares, so I have to write the conversion code.

Where `1 sq-meter = 9.2903e-6`

I have to call a function in which I have to write a conversion code.

So, how to write a exponential value in php?

Comment: Can't you use `9.2903 * pow(10, -6)`?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php. Basically, you write it just like that. Downvote from me because *you did not even try it* before asking (never mind reading the manual).

Comment: The way you're writing it is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [pow](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) function in php

Example:

```
<?php

var_dump(pow(2, 8)); // int(256)
echo pow(-1, 20); // 1
echo pow(0, 0); // 1

echo pow(-1, 5.5); // PHP >4.0.6  NAN
echo pow(-1, 5.5); // PHP <=4.0.6 1.#IND
?>
```

Comment: Or, he could just write `$x = 9.2903e-6;`. It works just like that.